# How use step into on Eclipse Debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning Java and I really love it. But I have a problem when I try to debug my Java First Project. Everything is on the picture.

[image: Source not found. Edit Source Lookup Path...]

Comment: You try to step into java's own classes, in this case `StringBuilder`. Usually, the sources of those classes are part of your JDK/SDK. Use the button in the picture to let eclipse know where it can find these sources.

Comment: I used the button but it still doesn't work. The same problem occurs...

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ specify a JDK (with sources) instead of the JRE (without sources) you have.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there should be no need to step into StringBuilder class. It is not a class that does something unexpected. You can see state of StringBuilder in debug variables view and if there was any exception it should be clear what the problem is.

You should add break point (from mouse right click menu on left side of editor) to source code where you want debug to pause:

[image: Adding break point]

Then you should step over (F6 key) the part calling StringBuilder.

[Here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) is good debugging tutorial.

If you really want to, you can configure sources in build path configuration:
[image: Build path configuration]
You can check visibility of sources without running application by opening StringBuilder class (CTRL + SHIFT + T, type and open StringBuilder).

Comment: I don't really understand where you're coming from. I'm just try to debug for my first time on Java and I should confess that I'm lost right now. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Adlo so did you add any break points to your HelloWorld class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I made it. I put two toggle breakpoints and my program is as simple as possible.

[image]